# problem when send ajax initiated payment laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, request

i have this problem when i want send an initiated payment
just work to me (beforeSend) all function not work
and didn't send the data to save transaction

```
<script>
    Moyasar.init({
        element: '.mysr-form',
        amount: {{ $order->total * 100 }},
        currency: 'SAR',
        description: 'مادة , رقم الطلب :   {{$order->id}} {{ $order->subject->name }}',
        publishable_api_key: '{{ config('moyasar.publishable_key') }}',
        callback_url: '{{ route('order.checkout', $order->id) }}',
        methods: [
            'creditcard',
        ],
        on_completed: function (payment) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '{{route('initialize_transaction')}}',
                method: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    'order': {{$order->id}},
                    'payment': payment.id,
                    '_token': '{{csrf_token()}}',
                },
                beforeSend : function() {
                    alert('before')
                },
                success: function () {
                    alert('success');
                },
                fail: function () {
                    alert('fail')
                },
                done: function () {
                    alert('done')
                }
            })
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: i try this but still same problem not work

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a double quote instead of a single quote in the URL parameter of ajax. This might solve your issue.

From

```
url: '{{route('initialize_transaction')}}',
```

TO

```
url: "{{route('initialize_transaction')}}",
```

If you still facing the problem then please check the console and give me error.

Comment: sorry for tell you , is still same problem for me just (beforeSend) alert it work with me

Comment: You need to do this for all the PHP variables like for order & _token.
`data: {
  'order': "{{$order->id}}",
  'payment': payment.id,
  '_token': "{{csrf_token()}}",
 },`